# Media Query x IE11

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Tried all, but media query not working in my Internet Explorer 11.
Respond.js can't tickled.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type='text/javascript' src="respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

I'm using this in css:

```
@media all and (max-width : 520px) {
```

The problem seems a very small detail. (from an inexperient programmer)
Please, take a minute and check out: [www.owlsports.com.br](http://www.owlsports.com.br) in your IE browser.

Comment: That media query works (I just tried it in IE11 on a test site). Also, respond.js is only going to run for IE 8 and under. Check the doctype I guess.

Comment: IE8 and under sucks, the doctype is ok. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what i did, but fixed the problem with http://validator.w3.org/, removing all erros in html5 and css files.

Seens IE don't like some bugs in your code :|

Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
@media (max-width: 520px) {

}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more about your solution.

Comment: This is my first sintaxe, not work ;/