# Media queries not working with ie & phones

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

My website does fit to the screens of different devices but my media query styles are not working. The problem is also visible when resizing the wordpress [website](http://www.owardilllandscapes.co.uk/) in an IE browser and when using a windows phone emulator (via IE 11). I've tried many different methods to fix this problem but so far none have been successful. All my media queries are in my main style.css

I've tried:

- Changing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
  As per: [Responsive web design is working on desktop but not on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device)

  - Changing `@media only screen and (max-width: XXXpx),only screen and (max-device-width: XXXpx)` in my style.css to `@media all and (max-width: XXXpx),all and (max-device-width: XXXpx)`
    As per: [Media Queries not working in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059414/media-queries-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11)
  - I've just deactivated -all- my plugins, cleared the cache, still unsuccessful.
  - I've also tried validating my website and cleaning up errors as per: [Media Query x IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108608/media-query-x-ie11)

I'm completely at a loss and frustrated as this hasn't happen with other websites I've designed and built. I'd appreciate any help I can get with this! Thank you.

Comment: did you refresh the page after starting the emulation?

Comment: Yes, I often do a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5?) and clear the cache to make sure.

Comment: try without the `max-device-width` parameter

Comment: I removed all the references to `max-device-width` but unfortunately that hasn't worked. Thank you for the suggestion though :)

Comment: Have you attempted to take out the "only screen" statements? Do the same issues occur if you shorten your queries to @media (max-width:XXXpx) {...}?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I changed all the 'only screen' parts to 'all' and shortened it as you suggested but that didn't work. The media queries are not being read by IE 11, as well as the older IE versions so I'm intrigued as to what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has now been solved. After deleting and tweaking files and sifting through support forums for answers, I looked at the stylesheet. It turns out I was missing a closing bracket inside a media query.

/Facepalm...